# Password entry keys Script fails to work after first use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I created an android type password keypad interface in HTML and CSS while using jQuery to enter the html numbered keys into the textarea box. While the script is working fine, the numbered pads stop working after the first use that is after entering the numbers for first time it doesn't work when user tries to enter the numbers for second time. However the numbers can be entered from the laptop keyboard.

```
jsfiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xxnutren/
```

Any help will be really helpful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$write.html($write.html() + character);
```

by this:

```
$write.val($write.val() + character);
```

`html()` sets the innerHTML of the element whereas `val()` sets the actual DOM value.

There are other things to correct but, [here is your updated **JSfiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xxnutren/1/)